# how to enable CDC in google cloud sql server for AWS DMS replication?

Tags: aws-aurora, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to migrate data from GCP cloud sql server to AWS aurora MySQL using DMS CDC, for this I need to enable CDC on DMS source database which cloud SQL. As per the AWS documentation I need to enable CDC by executing "sp_cdc_enable_db" SP and for this I need sysadmin access but google cloud don't support sysadmin access. So, in this scenario how to enable CDC?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe it's possible, but you can reach out to your Google Service Rep to confirm. You'll need to find an alternative way to migrate (such as taking a backup of the database and restoring in a SQL Server instance in AWS as intermediary step, then use the existing AWS services to migrate from SQL Server to MySQL).

Comment: Thanks J.D. for response. If I introduce intermediary step, target aurora mysql will not be in sync with source cloud sql and it's extra headache, not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: Yea unfortunately it's probably not the best solution (just an idea). You can talk to an AWS Solution Architect to see what other services might be able to help you migrate the data too. I know there's a couple other services besides DMS. They probably can guide you to the best alternative service in the case that CDC is not possible (but double check with your Google Rep if it's not possible to enable).

Comment: Thank you J.D for idea. Yes, its true that as per the GCP docs CDC and sysadmin feature are not available. ref - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/features#sqlserver-unavailable

Comment: No problem! Sorry, unfortunately moving data between cloud services can be tedious, but after you've completed the migration it will be easier. I think the reps from both services should be able to recommend the best course of action. Best of luck!